# Skip removing customly animated highlight from UITableViewCell when it's selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom animation in:

```
    - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

of the `UITableViewCell`, something like:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^{
        self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + 110, self.center.y);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        isShifted = finished;
    }];
```

The idea here is to shift the cell when the touch is down. Then if the cell is selected (no scrolling happened or cancel events) I proceed to another animation of the cell and transition to a new view.

The problem here is with an animation putting the cell back into its original position on `setHighlighted:NO` method call. Visually it looks like upon the selection the cell shifts (touch down), then starts going back (the system removes the highlight) and then starts the transition (the system calls `setSelected:YES`).

As far as I can see upon the selection of the cell in the table the following happens:

1. `setHighlighted:YES`
2. `setHighlighted:NO`
3. `setSelected:YES`

Is there any elegant solution to skip the call 2 and avoid the back-shifting-animation without introducing the timer that will check the selection?

Comment: are you using a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Yes, the controller inherits UITableViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of using the delegate method [`tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3ashouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath%3a)

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // The cell has been touched, perform custom animation here
    return NO;
}
```

`setHighlight:` will never be called on any cell, but you still have an entry point to perform the custom animation.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 cause you thought of same thing as me as the same time I was typing it in.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that one! I was staring at UITableViewController API docs for an hour and messing with cell's states... This delegate methods is exactly what solves my issue. Thanks a tone!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a delegate for your UITableView (presumably your own view controller), you can catch the selection happening via something like ["`tableView: willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a).

You can then do something "special" to your cell (such as set a property that forces the cell to do what you want in your animation) while the cell is selected.

And restore it back to what it was before when the cell is deselected via ["`tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDeselectRowAtIndexPath%3a).

You also have the same type of delegate methods available for highlighting, e.g. [`"tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3ashouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath%3a)

Comment: I think `willSelect...` is not appropriate, since *This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their finger*